# magento 2.3.1 - How to sort product name, price in ascending order in search result page?

Tags: catalogsearch, sorting, magento2.3.1, product-sorting

Below is my search result page sort by **product name** in result page.
Products are sorting by name by **Z to A**.

[image]

I want to show the products in **A-Z** order when user click **Product Name** sort By option.How can i do this?
in category page product sorting is working fine in **A - Z**.

Comment: Sort by Product Name in descending order is working fine in Magento 2.3.1 version. Please try by disabling you custom modules. May be some custom module is going to conflict.

Comment: @DharaBhatti category page its working fine, i want the same for search result page also.

Comment: I mean search page is working fine for descending Product Name sorting in default Magento 2.3.1. So please try once disabling all custom modules.

Comment: @DharaBhatti default magento 2.3.1 search page also sorting like Z-A.only category page is sorting A-Z

Comment: Can you please let me know do you used any extension or done any customization for sorting options? because as I can't see up/down arrow in your screenshot, like default magento 2.3.1 sorting arrow.

Comment: @DharaBhatti no i did not do any customization, my default magento 2.3.1 is fresh installed with sample data, no any code changes in that instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94636/discussion-between-mujahidh-and-dhara-bhatti).